# Error Occurred when verifying security for the message in MonoTouch using BasicHTTPbinding with SSL

Tags: web-services, soap, asynchronous, https, xamarin.ios

We are currently looking to use MonoTouch to develop a iPad app. We have an existing web service and client that connects fine, using basic httpbinding with a mProxy.Security.Mode of TransportWithMessageCredential (HTTPS).

We then add the client credentials using:
mProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
mProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "P@ssword";

However when we migrate this code to MonoTouch its errors verifying the security. We looked at the raw message recieved in both the windows and monotouch version and the monotouch version does not have any security credentials. I've read we will have to build these in manually. Is that the proper approach? Is there an easier way, or am I missing an easier way to do this. Please advise.

Comment: Can you post the code of how your bindings are setup in Windows versus MonoTouch?  MonoTouch does not have the ability to use config files.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, MonoTouch does not support WCF's Message Security mode.  They do mention that it is a work in progress.

I had the same requirement as you did and ended up following a recipe that uses basicHttpBinding, Transport security, basic credentials, and a custom HTTP module that uses the basic credentials in the HTTP "Authorization" header to authenticate a user (against the ASP.NET Membership Provider).

You can find implementation details here:

[How To – Use Username Authentication with Transport Security in WCF from Windows Forms](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20To%20-%20Use%20Username%20Authentication%20with%20Transport%20Security%20in%20WCF%20from%20Windows%20Forms&referringTitle=Home)